# How to stop OSX from issuing warning for sudo command in terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, sudo, sudoers

I have just updated to OSX Yosemite and every time I execute a `sudo` command, the OS issues this warning before the password prompt:

```
WARNING: Improper use of the sudo command could lead to data loss
or the deletion of important system files. Please double-check your
typing when using sudo.
```

How can this warning be silenced?

Comment: Mmmm... how pesky! Mine does that too.

Comment: Examining `/usr/bin/sudo` with HexFriend reveals that about halfway through the binary the string "WARNING: Improper use of the sudo command..." is hardcoded. It might be possible to remove this string (it seems like the end of the binary is a list of null-terminated strings separated by newlines), but I'll have to investigate further.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how this behaves, but it seems like this message only appears once (perhaps once per reboot).

Comment: There's an option, `lecture`, supported by the `sudoers` file. It defaults to giving that lecture once, but it can be set to `always`. Check that. If that's not set or already set to `once`, then the problem may be with the `sudo` database. That's where it would record that you had already been given the lecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the warning, open the sudoers file:

`sudo visudo`

Add this line (to keep it tidy, just after the other `Defaults`):

```
Defaults:al !lecture
```

I've tried to set it to just "once" (`Defaults   lecture = once`) but that seemed to be ignored.